# Semidefinite Hessian Matrix, Global and Local Extrema

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

Given the function $f(x,y) := x^2y$, which is defined on all $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le1\}$, the first partial derivatives are $0$ where $x=0$, however, the Hessian at all these points has the Eigenvalue $0$, it is semidefinite. We are supposed to find all local and global extrema. How does one handle the points where the Hessian is semidefinite? Do they have a name? Is it simply impossible to make a statement on local maxima/minima inside the compact set?

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind: global and local maxima and minima might occur on the boundary of your constraint set, and thus not be found by the usual calculus recipes.

Comment: @kimchi lover Thanks for the hint, but should I include or exclude the (0,y) values from my solution?

Comment: Your title, question, and comment are inconsistent.  Are you asked for local/global extrema, or critical points, or both?  Critical points, at least, you can find by calculus.

Comment: @kimchi lover Apologies, English is not the language I'm studying in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(t,t)=t^3$ and $f(0,t)=0$.

If $t>0$ we get $f(t,t)>f(0,t)$ and if $t<0$ we get $f(t,t)<f(0,t)$.

Conclusion: in $(0,t)$ the function $f$ has no local extremum

Answer (score 1):

I think you must search the optimum on the vurve $$x^2+y^2=1$$ so you will get
$$f(\pm\sqrt{1-y^2},y)=(1-y^2)y$$

Comment: Yes, but do I include the points (0,y) from the inside of the compact set in my solution set? They may be local extrema, and they may not be... Greetings from Germany. :)

Comment: One moment please, i will check my computation.

Comment: I this case you will get the local extrema

Comment: The global extrema are situated on the curve $$x^2+y^2=1$$